# Replacing a character is a string with a different character

Tags: java, regex, string

So this could be easy and I may be just over looking it, but I have a string array. I don't want two identical characters next to each other. I want to replace the second "a" with this case a "z" or any other character just not an "a" but I'm struggling to do it. Any advice?

I tried multiple different ways and looked up different methods on Google and I'm just stuck. I've tried `replace`, I've tried converting an integer into a `char` and replacing, I've tried just using an `=` (a `char`) but it didn't like that since `i+1` was an integer. I tried converting to a char array, changing the char then putting it back.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] test = {"aaaabbbb"};
        int totalChange;
        int[] changes = {test.length};
        char c = 'z';

        for(int z = 0; z <= test.length;z++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<= test[z].length();i++)
            {
                //System.out.println(test[z].charAt(i));
                if(test[z].charAt(i) == test[z].charAt(i+1))
                {
                    System.out.println(test[z].charAt(i+1));
                    test[z].replace(test[z].charAt(i+1), c);
                    System.out.println(test[z].charAt(i+1));
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. I want to copy & paste your code to give it a try. I am certainly not retyping it.

Comment: What are the different methods you found - list them here, maybe as [example]. Show what you've tried, with code, error output or unexpected console output.

Comment: `String[] test = {"aaaabbbb"};`  Why is this even an array?  This is currently simply an array with a single value, it could easily just be `String test = "aaaabbbb"`

Comment: without digging deeper in the code, I can already see 2 huge problems: outer loop should be `for(int z=0; z<test.length; z++)` and the inner loop should be `for(int i=0; i<test[z].length() - 1; i++)`

Comment: First fix your for loops so you won't get out of bounds errors. The outer loop, with `z`, should be `z < test.length`. The inner loop, with `i`, should be `i< test[z].length()-1` since you are accessing the character to the right of the current position. Then you need to assign the return value of `String.replace()` back to your original array position with `test[z] = test[z].replace(test[z].charAt(i+1), c);`. But the bigger problem is that replace is going to change ALL OCCURRENCES of that char to the replacement value. If you only want to replace that position then use a different approach.

Comment: **Strings are immutable** in Java.  You can reassign different Strings to String variables, but each String object itself can never be changed.  The `replace` method of String does not change the String, because Strings cannot be changed.  The method creates a new String value and returns it.  It’s up to you to make use of that returned value.

Comment: Could use a queue and a stack.

Comment: For the input `"aaaabbbb"`, what is the expected output? Can you provide more examples too?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main  {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test = "aaaabbbb";
        char c = 'z';
        
        char[] chars = test.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < chars.length -1 ;i++){

            if(chars[i] == chars[i+1] ){

                chars[i+1] = c;
            }
        }

        String output = new String( chars );

        System.out.println( output );
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach that works with any doubled character (except z) is to use [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
str = str.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "$1z");
```

---

Because your question says to replace with "z", dealing with doubled z's is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.replaceAll` method, which utilizes a regular expression pattern as it's first parameter.
You can use it to capture all characters which are immediately followed by another occurrence.

The following method will allow you to set the replacement character, as the `character` parameter.

```java
String replace(String string, char character) {
    return string.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "$1" + character);
}
```

Output for `replace("aaaabbbb", 'z')`.

```
azazbzbz
```